When waking from standby the display prior to sleep is shown for a few seconds on Debian12/KDE --- how to debug if it's fully going to Sleep?
I mentioned this issue here in a question about the built-in keyboard being turned off since recently when waking from sleep and this problem is probably linked to that.
When resuming from standby the screen before putting the laptop to sleep is shown, showing any open windows for 0.2 to 4 seconds (usually 2). This is a privacy problem but the bigger issue here is that I'm not sure anymore if it's actually going to Sleep.
A further indication that there could be issues with the process of going to sleep are:

when hibernating the device it powers down then after a sec powers up again to then truly power down after another sec (hibernation rather than sleep [suspend to swap partition] is my current workaround since the keyboard started to never work when resuming from sleep; it requires Secure Boot to be disabled)
the journalctl log entries at timestamps when resuming from sleep (so minutes after putting it to sleep) are often about it going to sleep; maybe it goes into actual sleep before all go-to-sleep procedures are finished which are then only completed at a later point or the timestamps are just off; details in the other question linked above and I could provide some more logs but the logs vary per test
on another machine with a nearly identical setup but already on Debian11 the keyboard often turns on several minutes after putting the machine to sleep (no noise, no working fans, no other lights); I think this started to occur a few months ago; the question about that is here

Assuming you don't know what the problem could be and that this isn't a known problem: how to debug it? For example, how to test or see how much it goes to sleep and if there are any issues with it?
As for a bug report, info what the relevant package would be would also be useful. KDE Plasma is version 5.27.5. As said, currently I'm using hibernation and there the problem can't occur but I could change it back for doing some quick tests (since this could be a problem if it also affects other users).
Also it seems like once when waking from sleep I didn't have to enter my password, so something didn't work right at putting it to sleep. It's not clear from the journalctl logs what exactly went wrong. It has kwin_wayland_wrapper[3823110]: qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate() and org.kde.powerdevil: Failed to start suspend job "org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress" "There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress" before suspend (it did turn off). When resuming first entries are kernel: Filesystems sync: xx.xxx seconds`` kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.xxx seconds) done. and a bit further down kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000] and further down systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend. systemd-logind[659]: Operation 'sleep' finished.. Again, I'm using Debian12 stable and I think there should be a way to verify sleep and resume work as they should (apparently they don't).
